# Numbers above staff (8.8.8.6)

Tags: theory, notation

What do the numbers above the staff mean? In this case 8. 8. 8. 6. [image]

Answer (score 8):

Those numbers represent the [meter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre_(hymn)) the verses. That is the number of syllables in each line of each stanza. Generally, though there are exceptions, songs with the same meter can be sung with the same melody.

Comment: To nitpick just a little bit: having the same number of syllables doesn't always guarantee that two songs can be sung to the same melody, as the stresses could be different between them. But *generally* what you've said is true, especially for the most common meters.

Comment: That's true. I embarrassed myself once by picking the only pair in my church hymnal that doesn't work to demonstrate. So you're right. I'll change it to generally.

Comment: Thank for the explanations!  Does it have anything to do with the speed of playing/singing??  I was told it did... but not by an expert.

Comment: Not really a whole lot. As hopper said the difference is with which syllables are empahsized. It would basically break in a way that is similar to how counting the wrong time during a piece fails it just feels wrong. You can try to force it but sometimes it just doesn't fit. If you're using a hymnal it might have an index of meters. In which case you can look there to see a song that you know and one that you don't. You could then try singing the words of the one that you don't to the melody that you do. I'll update my answer with some images to reflect that.

Comment: I tried singing a few just now. If your friend meant "Sometimes it you have to sing it faster to make it fit" yes but no. You might have to sing the words faster to make it sound like you are accustomed to, but it should work at any tempo.

Comment: Thank you for your patient (and abundantly tolerant) explanations.  
My acute case of bounded rationality in this instance is considerably eased!